# Optimizing Non-Linear Langmuir Parameter Estimation in R

Tags: r, data-fitting, nls, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I am interested in using `nls` to aid in fitting the Langmuir Equation `Y =(Qmax*k*X)/(1+(k*X))`  similar to what was done in this post [Fitting Non-linear Langmuir Isotherm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903247/fitting-non-linear-langmuir-isotherm-in-r#). The parameter of the equation I am interested in is `Qmax` which corresponds to the horizontal asymptote (green line) of the plotted sorption data below. Is there a more robust approach other than `nls` or a way to improve my use of `nls` that I could employ to get a `Qmax` value as close as possible to the visual asymptote (green line) around `Qmax=3200`?

```
Lang <- nls(formula = Y ~ (Qmax*k*X)/(1+(k*X)),  data = data, start = list(Qmax = 3600, k = 0.015), algorith = "port")
```

Using the following data:

```
     X        Y
1    3.08   84.735
2    5.13  182.832
3    6.67  251.579
4    9.75  460.077
5   16.30  779.350
6   25.10  996.540
7   40.80 1314.739
8   68.90 1929.422
9  111.00 2407.668
10 171.00 3105.850
11 245.00 3129.240
12 300.00 3235.000
```

I'm getting a `Qmax = 4253.63` (red line) - approximately 1000 units away. Using upper and lower limits only results in a Qmax of what I set the upper limit to and changing initial values doesn't appear to change the outcome. Is this a challenge that can be solved with a different approach to non-linear regression than I've taken in base R or is this a statistical/mathematical problem first and foremost?

[Plot of Non-linear Langmuir Isotherm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA2Su.png)

```
 summary(Lang)

    Formula: Y ~ (Qmax * k * X)/(1 + (k * X))

Parameters:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Qmax 4.254e+03  1.554e+02   27.37 9.80e-11 ***
k    1.209e-02  1.148e-03   10.53 9.87e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 99.14 on 10 degrees of freedom

Algorithm "port", convergence message: relative convergence (4)
```

My attempt at the linearization of the model was less successful:

```
z <- 1/data
plot(Y~X,z)
abline(lm(Y~X,z))
M <- lm(Y~X,z)

Qmax <- 1/coef(M)[1]
#4319.22

k <- coef(M)[1]/coef(M)[2]
#0.00695
```

Disclaimer: This is my first post so please bear with me, and I'm relatively new to R. With that being said any technical advice that might help me improve my technique above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you expect `Qmax` to be that low

I rewrote your dependency in a simplest form, removing multiplication and replacing it with addition (a => 1/k) by dividing both nominator and denominator by `k`. Result looks perfect to my eye.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("R/Langmuir.dat", sep = " ")

Lang <- nls(formula = Y ~ (Qmax*X)/(a+X),  data = dt, start = list(Qmax = 3600, a = 100.0), algorithm = "port")
q <- summary(Lang)

Qmax <- q$coefficients[1,1]
a    <- q$coefficients[2,1]

f <- function(x, Qmax, a) {
    (Qmax*x)/(a+x)
}

p <- ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = X, y = Y))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + xlab("T") + ylab("Q") + ggtitle("Langmuir Fit")
p <- p + stat_function(fun = function(x) f(x, Qmax=Qmax, a=a))
print(p)

print(Qmax)
print(a)
```

Output

```
4253.631
82.68501
```

Graph

[image]

UPDATE

Basically, too many points at low X, hard to get curve bending for lower Qmax. Designed way to make curve bend is to add weights. For example, if I add weights column after reading data table:

```
dt[, W := (as.numeric(N)/12.0)^3]
```

and run `nls` with weights

```
Lang <- nls(formula = Y ~ (Qmax*X)/(a+X),  data = dt, start = list(Qmax = 3600, a = 100.0), weights = dt$W, algorithm = "port")
```

I'll get `Qmax` and `a`

```
[1] 4121.114
[1] 74.89386
```

with the following graph

[image]